# ELMo Embedding layer with Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, word-embedding

I have been using Keras default embedding layer with word embeddings in my architecture. Architecture looks like this -

```
left_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')
right_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length,
                            trainable=False)

# Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden, name="lstm")

left_output = shared_lstm(encoded_left)
right_output = shared_lstm(encoded_right)
```

I want to replace the embedding layer with ELMo embeddings. So I used a custom embedding layer - found in this repo - https://github.com/strongio/keras-elmo/blob/master/Elmo%20Keras.ipynb. Embedding layer looks like this -

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.dimensions = 1024
    self.trainable=True
    super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable,
                           name="{}_module".format(self.name))

    self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
    super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                  as_dict=True,
                  signature='default',
                  )['default']
    return result

def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    return K.not_equal(inputs, '--PAD--')

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.dimensions)
```

I changed the architecture for the new embedding layer.

```
 # The visible layer
left_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
right_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")

embedding_layer = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()

# Embedded version of the inputs
encoded_left = embedding_layer(left_input)
encoded_right = embedding_layer(right_input)

# Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden, name="lstm")

left_output = shared_gru(encoded_left)
right_output = shared_gru(encoded_right)
```

But I am getting error -

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get any errors with k.tf.trainable_variables?

Comment: I am getting the ame error @ElSheikh, could you find a solution?

Comment: Yes [ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11897007/ivan-libedinsky), here you go
`self._trainable_weights += tf.trainable_variables(scope=f"^{self.name}_module/.*")`

Comment: Did it help you? @IvanLibedinsky

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm having with tensorflow and trainable_variables, could you specify which tensforflow and keras versions were you using when you managed to run this?

Comment: Solved, I needed to change drowngrade to version 1.13 I was using 2.0.0 thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also used that repository as a guide to build a CustomELMo + BiLSTM + CRF model, and I needed to change the dict lookup to 'elmo' instead of 'default'. As Anna Krogager pointed out, when the dict lookup is 'default' the output is (batch_size, dim), which isn't enough dimensions for the LSTM. However when the dict lookup is ['elmo'] the layer returns a tensor of the right dimensions, namely of shape (batch_size, max_length, 1024).

Custom ELMo Layer:

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.dimensions = 1024
    self.trainable = True
    super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable,
                           name="{}_module".format(self.name))

    self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
    super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                       as_dict=True,
                       signature='default',
                       )['elmo']
    print(result)
    return result

# def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
#   return K.not_equal(inputs, '__PAD__')

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape[0], 48, self.dimensions
```

And the model is built as follows:

```
def build_model(): # uses crf from keras_contrib
    input = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    model = ElmoEmbeddingLayer(name='ElmoEmbeddingLayer')(input)
    model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True))(model)
    crf = CRF(num_tags)
    out = crf(model)
    model = Model(input, out)
    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf_loss, metrics=[crf_accuracy, categorical_accuracy, mean_squared_error])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I hope my code is useful to you, even if it's not exactly the same model. Note that I had to comment out the compute_mask method as it throws

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,47] vs. [32,0]    [[{{node loss/crf_1_loss/mul_6}}]]
```

where 32 is batch size and 47 is one less than my specified max_length (presumably meaning it's accounting for a pad token itself). I haven't worked out the cause of that error yet, so it might be fine for you and your model. However I notice you're using GRU's, and there's an unresolved issue on the repository about adding GRU's. So I'm curious whether you get that isue too.

Comment: Why the input size is `(1,)`? How would that work? `input = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)`

Answer (score 2):

The Elmo embedding layer outputs one embedding per input (so the output shape is `(batch_size, dim)`) whereas your LSTM expects a sequence (i.e. shape `(batch_size, seq_length, dim)`). I don't think it makes much sense to have an LSTM layer after an Elmo embedding layer since Elmo already uses an LSTM to embed a sequence of words.

Comment: What shold I change in the ELMo embedding layer in order to get the LSTM expected sequence?

Comment: What do you want to obtain with your LSTM layer? Your input is just a string, not a sequence, so I don't understand what the purpose of your LSTM layer is. But if you would somehow have a sequence of strings as input then you could apply the ELMo layer to each element of the sequence (by wrapping ELMo in a TimeDistributed layer) and then feed the resulting sequence of embeddings to the LSTM

Comment: Yeah, actually my input is a sentence